# Karate afterScenario global hook

Tags: karate

Is it possible to configure `afterScenario` hook globally?

I can configure per `.feature` file like this:

```
  Background:
    * url baseMhsServiceUrl
    * configure afterScenario =
      """
      function(){
        var uri = karate.prevRequest.url;
        karate.log('Request was: ' + uri);
      }
      """
```

But, I tried this in the karate.config.js  and it is not working at all.

```
karate.configure('afterScenario', "function(){var uri = karate.prevRequest.url;\nkarate.log('Request was: ' + uri);}");
```

Could not find such an example in the docs.

Comment: and yes, the docs suck :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, do consider contributing code.

But you have the option of writing a `RuntimeHook`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#hooks