# Implement tag rule check before running karate

Tags: karate

I want to check if all the scenarios have a specific tag before executing them.

I found out this can be done post-execution with the results of Runner.path(). But was wondering if we can do it before execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a custom [RuntimeHook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68676001/143475). You can find an example [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.1/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/runner/hooks/MandatoryTagHook.java).